# ¿Como obtener los nietos de una lista de hijos de un nodo padre en Firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, recyclerview

Actualmente estoy trabajado con Firebase y Android. Estoy tratando de hacer un sistema de Rating para una lista de Restaurantes pero me he encontrado con un detalle, no se como puedo obtener los nietos de una lista de hijos de un nodo padre para luego sacar el promedio de cada Restaurante.

El nodo padre hace referencia al contenedor de los id de cada Restaurante, dentro tengo una lista de las calificaciones de los usuarios de ese Restaurante y estoy tratando de obtener todos los restaurantes calificados con sus calificaciones y adjuntar los resultados en un RecyclerView pero no se como hacerlo correctamente.

**SOLUCION**

No se si es la solución mas eficiente pero logre hacer que funcionara, lo que hice fue crear dos variebles List<> y un HashMap <>.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El primer List<> para almacenar la información básica del Restaurante (Id, Nombre, Especialidad, etc...), el HashMap<> para almacenar el (**id**) de cada Restaurante como clave y el (**rating**) como valor y la ultima variable List<> para juntar toda la información en una sola lista para luego pasarla al RecyclerView. (Para esto cree también 3 clases POJO)

**calcular el promedio**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Función para juntar toda la información**

[image: Función para juntar toda la información]

El nodo de la base de datos en Firebase lo cambie y quedo así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Para obtener todos los ratings debajo del nodo padre data podes hacer lo siguiente

primero creamos una clase pojo con los datos que queres traer, tienen que tener el mismo nombre que en firebase y tipo de dato.

**RestaurantPojo.class**

```
public class RestaurantPojo{

    private int rating;

    public RestaurantPojo(){

    }


    public int getRating() {
        return rating;
    }

    public void setRating(int rating) {
        this.rating = rating;
    }


}
```

Luego solo pedimos los datos una vez de todos los restaurantes

```
mDatabase.child("Ratings").child("data").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
  @Override
  public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    //Recorremos todos los hijos debajo de data y obtenemos los ratings
    for(DataSnapshot snapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
    RestaurantPojo rp = snapshot.getValue(RestaurantPojo.class);
    //Obtenemos los valores que queres
     int rating = rp.getRating();
     //Para obtener el padre que contiene cada rating podes hacer lo siguiente 
     String padre = snapshot.getKey();

      Log.e("Datos: " , "" + rating);

       }

  }

  @Override
  public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
    System.out.println("The read failed: " + databaseError.getCode());
  }
});
```

Donde mDatabase es

```
DatabaseReference mDatabase;

mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
```

Comment: He probado la solución pero obtengo como resultado del campo rating "0" a menos que agregue un hijo directo a "data" llamado rating. (edito mi pregunta con la imagen del resultado).

Comment: como generas el child despues de data?

Comment: Cuando un usuario califica un Restaurante se guarda en "data" el id de ese Restaurante junto con la calificación. la idea es que cuando otro usuario califique el mismo Restaurante la calificación no se guarde en "data" sino como hijo del "id" del Restaurante formado así una lista de calificaciones que solo pertenece a ese Restaurante.